# Java Util Logging Level using Classpath

Tags: java, java.util.logging

is it possible to specify the logging level for java.util.logging using classpath? I don't want to use for that special file or create java class which overrides the default level.

My point is to say something like this -Djava.util.logging.level=ERROR

I can't find it in documentation, but maybe there are some tricks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The Java Logging API can be configured either with a configuration class `java.util.logging.config.class` or with a configuration file. A default logging configuration file is located at `"lib/logging.properties"`, inside the JRE directory.
You could change this configuration file (which is not the best idea as it will be used for all the programs running in this JRE) or 
 you could set a separate configuration file for your application and set JVM property `java.util.logging.config.file` to point to this file

`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/tmp/logging.properties`

See [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-logging/configuration.html) for more details on Java Logging configuration.